# Unable to keep the static data for the input type fields in angular material

Tags: user-input, angular-material

How to make a default static value for input in material design?

```
<input type="text" value="xyz"  />
```

but in material design angular I am unable to keep the static value like `value="xyz`

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Start date</label>
    <input ng-model="agg.startDate" value="xyz">
</md-input-container>"
```

value `xyz` is not affected in this case.

Comment: How to make an default static value for input in material design...

<input type="text" value="xyz"  />

but in material design angulat I am unable to keep the static value like value="xyz

<md-input-container><label>Start date</label><input ng-model="agg.startDate" value="xyz">
</md-input-container>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller create a variable named `agg.startDate` using the `$scope` variable, like following code to set the value of input field

```
$scope.agg = {startDate: 'xyz'};
```

[check this fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/salalaslam/swrq6xb3/)